# Sitecore Azure PaaS Deployment - ResourceDeploymentFailure | DeploymentFailed | BadRequest

Tags: azure, deployment, paas

Anyone got the same issue upon the provisioning of Sitecore Web Experience Manager (XM) using Azure PaaS offering.

I've just followed the steps provided in Azure with $50 remaining credits in my account, but while the '**deployment in progress...**' suddenly it failed after 20-30 minutes.

[image]

1. Create a new Resource Group name
2. Configure the Sitecore Settings

   - Version: v.8.2 Update 4 or Update 5
   - Topology: Sitecore Web Experience Manager (XM)
   - Size: 1-3
   - Location: West Europe (Tried Southeast asia too)
   - Application Insights: West Europe
   - Credentials: *****
3. Accept the License Agreement and hit OK.

**Here's the error message:**

[image]

Code:

```
{  
   "status":"Failed",
   "error":{  
      "code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure",
      "message":"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
      "details":[  
         {  
            "code":"DeploymentFailed",
            "message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
            "details":[  
               {  
                  "code":"BadRequest",
                  "message":"{\r\n \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n \"message\": \"Bad Request\",\r\n \"innererror\": {\r\n \"diagnosticcontext\": \"f4007f36-398d-4f6f-a408-8eca6d373549\",\r\n \"time\": \"2017-10-24T03:58:53.3083676Z\"\r\n }\r\n}"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Moreover, I've checked this article from MS on how to troubleshoot azure deployment issues, but it doesn't totally makes sense to me as it's just plain and simple 'follow-the-steps-in-azure' - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors

**[Update-1]** To add, the resources are visible and I can go to each details.

[image]

I can even hit the URL of the Sitecore CM and the page will load fine. However, I have noticed that upon page load it will display the azure page and not the sitecore default homepage, also the /sitecore/login is not accessible.

[image]

Note that I've done this few months back, but then when I tried now I received this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am trying to create a Sitecore Experience Cloud v9 using Microsoft Azure and I am getting this error message: *"code": "BadRequest", "message": "Bad Request", "innererror"...:*
It doesn't say much about the problem. I have Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN subscription. I removed the limits and added a payment method.
Is anything else that I can do to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard from the sitecore support, and it is related to the following know issue related to Visual Studio limited subscription: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/915122.

Thus, to resolve the issue, try to remove limits by settings a payment method in your subscription.

This query is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Azure doesn't make it super easy to see the issues, but there is *usually* a more detailed error along with the basic error you've provided which is what helped me determine the exact error.  I do believe there is an issue with a change Azure made in regards to SQL Azure compatibility which is possibly related (it was impacting me w/ my deployments).  See this kb article for details:  https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/755670.  The SC ARM templates out on the GitHub repo have been updated to account for this, so you could deploy using PowerShell w/ those templates to see if that works for you.